# Rust BTreeMap - what is the equivalent of a "peek" or "first" function?

Tags: rust, btreemap

Binary Trees have a root node. Typically with such a data structure implementation, a function is provided to "peek" the root node, as well as the smallest and largest elements.

In other words, in Rust world, I would like to be able to do this:

```
let map = BTreeMap::new(); // contains T

map.first(); // -> Option<T>
map.last(); // -> Option<T>
```

I would have expected to find such a function in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html), but did not.

What I did find is a function called `first_entry` and similarly a function called `last_entry`.

I assume `first_entry` does something like what I want, but I don't understand how to use it since it returns a type `OccupiedEntry`. ([doc link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/btree_map/struct.OccupiedEntry.html))

I would assume that `first_entry` is `O(log(N))` and `last_entry` is `O(log(N))`, and should there be a similar function for the root, then that would be `O(1)`. (Less important.)

Comment: The nomenclature is confusing but `BTreeMap` is **not a binary tree**, it's a [b-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

Comment: @Masklinn either way, I would expect to have a function to "get the root"

Comment: The root of a btree is an internal node (though a special case thereof), it has no content. Hell, that barely make sense in binary trees, in a BST (like an rbtree or an avltree) the root is just a median-ish value.

Comment: Your complexity bounds also don't make sense, trees generally work in logarithmic time, why would `last_entry` ever be linear. That's the complexity of a sorted association list.

Comment: @Masklinn yes, don't know why I put `O(N)` there, have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first_entry()` and `last_entry()` are for *manipulating* the entries. For just accessing them, there are [`first_key_value()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.first_key_value) and [`last_key_value()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.last_key_value).

If I understand correctly, both first and last functions are O(log N).

Answer (score -1):

One possible way to make this work is as follows. (However there are better solutions described in other answers.)

There is a function on the object `OccupiedEntry` called `get`. This returns a reference to the underlying data.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/btree_map/struct.OccupiedEntry.html#method.get

Comment: The auxiliary object is just the interface map/set data structures in std use. The idea is that, while you hold this auxiliary object, depending on if you have an exclusive borrow, a shared borrow or own it, you don't have the same "rights" to access the underlying data, yet a single interface is provided. However, you don't *need* to go through it, you can also call [`first_key_value`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.first_key_value) for instance.

Comment: This answer still reads as if you are asking another question. I would advise to stop using rhetorical questions.

Comment: @Dharman it's not a rhetorical question? Why would you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Because this is an answer... You cannot expect to receive an answer to an answer. So either this is not an answer and should be removed, or it's a rhetorical question that is part of the solution you are providing.